# How to make specific window active

Tags: autoit

I want to know how to make a window (like Google Chrome, Notepad) active as If I were to click on it with the cursor. I've searched on Google but I couldn't find anything.

Can someone please tell me which function to use and what parameters it uses.
Here's what I already tried using

```
WinWaitActive("Gestion de Voyage")
```

But **WinWaitActive** waits for the window to be active instead of activating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WinActivate` should do what you're looking for.

https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinActivate.htm

What you're trying to do is change window focus.

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept my answer as the solution if it worked for you.

Comment: it say i need to wait 8 minutes

Answer (score 0):

If it's for a specific Control inside a window, use [ControlFocus](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlFocus.htm).